# Server to server authentication

Tags: authentication, server

I need to perform sensitive REST API calls between 2 server applications that I am writing. To do this I need to be able authenticate the server that is performing the sensitive API calls.

The current architecture + what I need to add in orange:

[image: Image of the architecture]

*All servers are exposed to the internet.
What I thought to do is:

1. Limit sensitive API calls by IP
2. All sensitive API calls will need a secret key (do I need to use HMAC here?) that will be validated on the API server

What do you think? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use mutual TLS?

Comment: @Crowman I didn't that there is such a thing as mutual TLS, I will look it up.
Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use mutually authenticated TLS. This will only authenticate the communicating parties.

Comment: What do you think about JWT?

Comment: Just to be clear, JWT is a token format. Not an authentication mechanism.

Comment: JWT tokens can be used rather than mTLS. However then you will need to be able produce and validate tokens. mTLS should be available out the box.